# The closure of union of infinitely many subsets having the same closure

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ a topological space  and  $A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots$ an infinite sequence of subsets of $X$ such that for any $i \in \mathbb N$ we have $\operatorname{CL}(A_i)=F$. I mean they all have the same closure set.

I would like to enquire whether $\operatorname{CL}( \cup A_i ) = F$ or not.

Is this true or not, and how can I prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Cl(\bigcup A_i)\subset F$.

$Cl(A_i)=F$ implies that $A_i\subset F$ for every $i$, thus $\bigcup A_i\subset F$. Since $Cl(\bigcup A_i)$ is the smallest subset which contains $\bigcup A_i$, we deduce that $Cl(\bigcup A_i)\subset F$

$F\subset Cl(\bigcup A_i)$.

Let $C$ be a closed subset which contains $\bigcup A_i$, for every $i$, $A_i\subset C$ this implies $Cl(A_i)= F\subset Cl(C)=C$, this implies that $F\subset \cap_{C closed, \bigcup A_i\subset C}C= Cl(\bigcup A_i)$.

Thus $Cl(\bigcup A_i)=F$.